# jQuery modal funnieness in IE

Tags: jquery

I nabbed this jQuery modal login http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/login-box-modal-dialog-window-with-css-and-jquery/ and it works great in chrome and FF - and it works in IE on the demo page, but when I implement it - even in a super basic form, it doesn't work...

The modal mask works, but the login form render behind the mask and in the upper left corner, not centered...not to mention the form doesn't even render...

It get weird for me as I try to convey it - in jsfiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/n2bFt/8/
```

even in IE it works (making me think jsfiddle uses a webkit rendering engine for that window)

HOWEVER if you run the page straight in IE9 - it fubars...

any ideas....please...

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mask { display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 999; width: 100%; height: 100%; background:#7d949a; opacity: 0.8; filter:alpha( opacity=80 ); }

.login-popup{ display:none; position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; z-index: 9999; float: left; background: #333; padding: 10px; border: 2px solid #ddd; font-size: 1.2em; box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* Firefox */ -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; /* Safari, Chrome */   border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;  -moz-border-radius: 3px; /* Firefox */ -webkit-border-radius: 3px; /* Safari, Chrome */ }

img.btn_close { float: right; margin: -28px -28px 0 0; }
fieldset { border:none; }
form.signin .textbox label { display:block; padding-bottom:7px; }
form.signin .textbox span { display:block; }
form.signin p, form.signin span { color:#999; font-size:11px; line-height:18px; } 
form.signin .textbox input { width:200px; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:6px 6px 4px; background:#666666;     border-bottom:1px solid #333; border-left:1px solid #000; border-right:1px solid #333; border-top:1px     solid #000; color:#fff; 
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; }
form.signin input:-moz-placeholder { color:#bbb; text-shadow:0 0 2px #000; }
form.signin input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#bbb; text-shadow:0 0 2px #000; }
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
$( 'a.login-window' ).click( function() {

    // Getting the variable's value from a link 
    var loginBox = $( this ).attr( 'href' );

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $( loginBox ).fadeIn( 300 );

    //Set the center alignment padding + border
    var popMargTop = ( $( loginBox ).height() + 24 ) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ( $( loginBox ).width() + 24 ) / 2; 

    $( loginBox ).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });

    // Add the mask to body
    $( 'body' ).append( '<div id="mask"></div>' );
    $( '#mask' ).fadeIn( 300 );

    return false;
});

// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$( 'a.close, #mask' ).on( 'click', function() { 
    $( '#mask, .login-popup' ).fadeOut( 300 , function() {
        $( '#mask' ).remove();  
    }); 

    return false;
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" >

<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
<form method="post" class="signin" action="#">
    <fieldset class="textbox">
    <label class="username"><span>Email</span>
        <input id="username" name="username" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username">
    </label>

    <label class="password"><span>Password</span>
        <input id="password" name="password" value="" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </label>

    <button class="submit button" type="button">Sign in</button>

    <p><a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>

    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<span style="font-size: 8pt; color: #707070;" ><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Client Login</a>&copy; 2012-</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope you aren't planning to use "modality" to prevent interaction with the page prior to login, because that's never secure. (Never trust the browser).

Comment: no Gus, this is just the UI - the content will be secured on the back end.